# I want to map over an array using React which in turn contains an object

Tags: reactjs

I have an array which is structured as follows. I got this array from a postgresql db as:

> [{"pp_all":"{"pp_ident":43,"pp_titel":"abc","pp_beschreibung":null}]

I use REACT to map over this array.

```
 {gesamt.map((elemt, index) => (
        <>
          <h5 key={index}>{elemt.pp_all}</h5>
        </>
 ))}
```

As a result I get the following to see in my browser:

> {"pp_ident":43,"pp_titel":"abc","pp_beschreibung":null}

How do I get the value of the individual attributes?

**EDIT**

If i hover over the result data.pp_all i got the follwowing :

> "{"pp_ident":43,"pp_titel":"abc","pp_beschreibung":null}"

So i think it is the wrong format in the frontend.
But how can it be, because if i print it out, i can see the above

And if i trie to do the following:

```
 {gesamt.map((data) => {
    console.log(data.pp_all.pp_titel);
 })}
```

I got an undefined error

Comment: `<h5 key={index}>{elemt.pp_all.pp_ident}</h5>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to target individual attribute with another dot. Like the following

```
{elemt.pp_all.pp_indent}
{elemt.pp.all.pp_titel} and so on..
```

Because you got the object so it works same like you would target and object's property

Answer (score 0):

The answers absove will show you how to access the individual fields, but if you want to display all values the way you presented your html, you could loop over the keys of that object and return the value like this:

```
 {gesamt.map((elemt, index) => (
        <>
          <h5 key={index}>{Object.keys(elemt.pp_all).map(key => elemt.pp_all[key])}</h5>
        </>
 ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to iterate over each object to get attribute value

```
gesamt.map(data => {    
   for (let key in data ) {
       <h5>{data[key].pp_titel}</h5>
       <h4>{data[key].pp_ident}</h4>
   }
})
```